# Omnipay: PayPal and Stripe sale_id for refund?

Tags: paypal, omnipay

I'm trying to refund transactions via Omnipay and it looks like Omnipay supports [refunds](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal/blob/master/src/Message/RestRefundRequest.php#L28). However the documentation isn't clear and I've some confusion about how to go about this.

Omnipay Example code for refund:

```
    $transaction = $gateway->refund(array(
        'amount'    => '10.00',
        'currency'  => 'AUD',
    ));
    $transaction->setTransactionReference($sale_id);
    $response = $transaction->send();
    if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
        echo "Refund transaction was successful!\n";
        $data = $response->getData();
        echo "Gateway refund response data == " . print_r($data, true) . "\n";
    }
```

What's the $sale_id here? My Payments table has transaction id saved as:

```
'PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID' => $data['PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID'],
```

Which looks like: `01H36802XU637613S` (PayPal) & `ch_1IYpA7BJRxbFR9rFrGmPKs85` (Stripe).  Are these the `$sale_id`?

Answer (score 1):

This is really something Omnipay will likely have to answer on the whole, but maybe this helps:

`ch_1IYpA7BJRxbFR9rFrGmPKs85` would be what you'd use to create a refund in Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds/create#create_refund-charge